# Ring buffer with random access

Tags: java, array, reinventing-the-wheel, library, circular-list

I had an application where I really wanted a double-ended queue that supports random access. Java's `ArrayDeque` would have been perfect, except that it doesn't expose random access into its backing array. So I went and implemented my own, which I named `RingBuffer`.

I'm looking for any constructive criticism about either the data structure implementation itself, or the test suite.

Implementation:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class RingBuffer<T> {

    private Object[] backingArray;
    private int firstIdx = 0;   // Index of the first elements
    private int nextIdx = 0;    // Index of the slot into which we would insert an element on addLast
                                // If nextIdx == (firstIdx - 1) % array_size, then insertion requires resizing the array.
                                // If nextIdx == firstIdx, then the buffer is empty.

    public RingBuffer() {
        backingArray = new Object[2];
    }

    synchronized private void doubleBackingArraySize() {
        int newSize = backingArray.length * 2;
        Object[] newArray = new Object[newSize];
        int oldSize;

        if (nextIdx < firstIdx) {
            int numElementsToEndOfArray = backingArray.length - firstIdx;
            System.arraycopy(backingArray, firstIdx, newArray, 0, numElementsToEndOfArray);
            System.arraycopy(backingArray, 0, newArray, numElementsToEndOfArray, nextIdx);
            oldSize = numElementsToEndOfArray + nextIdx;
        } else {
            // This will happen if firstIdx == 0
            System.arraycopy(backingArray, firstIdx, newArray, 0, nextIdx - firstIdx);
            oldSize = nextIdx - firstIdx;
        }

        backingArray = newArray;
        // Update our indices into that array.
        firstIdx = 0;
        nextIdx = oldSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements that the array backing this can hold.
     * This is NOT necessarily the number of elements presently in the buffer.
     * Useful for testing that the implementation works correctly, and for figuring out if an add{First, Last} will
     * cause a re-allocation.
     */
    public int capacity() {
        return backingArray.length - 1;
    }

    /**
     * The number of elements currently held in the buffer.
     */
    public int size() {
        if (firstIdx <= nextIdx) {
            return nextIdx - firstIdx;
        } else {
            return (backingArray.length - firstIdx + nextIdx);
        }
    }

    public void addLast(T x) {
        if ((nextIdx + 1) % backingArray.length == firstIdx) {
            doubleBackingArraySize();
        }

        backingArray[nextIdx] = x;
        nextIdx +=1;
        nextIdx %= backingArray.length;
    }

    public void addFirst(T x) {
        if ((nextIdx + 1) % backingArray.length == firstIdx) {
            doubleBackingArraySize();
        }

        firstIdx -= 1;
        // Note: in Java -1 % n == -1
        if (firstIdx < 0) {
            firstIdx += backingArray.length;
        }
        backingArray[firstIdx] = x;
    }

    public void removeFirst() {
        if (size() == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            firstIdx += 1;
            firstIdx %= backingArray.length;
        }
    }

    public void removeLast() {
        if (size() == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            nextIdx -= 1;
            if (nextIdx < 0) {
                nextIdx += backingArray.length;
            }
        }
    }

    public T getFromFirst(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T)backingArray[(firstIdx + i) % backingArray.length];
        }
    }

    public T getFromLast(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            int idx = nextIdx - 1 - i;
            if (idx < 0) {
                idx += backingArray.length;
            }
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T)backingArray[idx];
        }
    }

}
```

Tests:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class RingBufferTests {

    @Test
    public void populateAndRandomAccess() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addLast(5); // [5]
        buffer.addLast(6); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7); // [5, 6, 7]

        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void populateAndRandomAccessFromLast() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addLast(5); // [5];
        buffer.addLast(6); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7); // [5, 6, 7]

        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromLast(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromLast(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromLast(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void populateFromFirst() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addFirst(5); // [5]
        buffer.addFirst(6); // [6, 5]
        buffer.addFirst(7); // [7, 6, 5]

        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromLast(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromLast(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromLast(2));

        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void populateFromBothEnds() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addFirst(6); // [6]
        buffer.addFirst(5); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7);  // [5, 6, 7]
        buffer.addLast(8);  // [5, 6, 7, 8]

        Assert.assertEquals(8, (int)buffer.getFromLast(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromLast(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromLast(2));
        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromLast(3));

        Assert.assertEquals(5, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(2));
        Assert.assertEquals(8, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void outOfBoundsAccessThrows() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addLast(5); // [5]
        buffer.addLast(6); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7); // [5, 6, 7]

        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromFirst(3));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromFirst(4));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromFirst(5));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromLast(3));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromLast(4));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromLast(5));

        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromFirst(-1));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> buffer.getFromLast(-1));
    }

    @Test
    public void removingWhenEmptyThrows() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addLast(5); // [5]
        buffer.addLast(6); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7); // [5, 6, 7]

        buffer.removeFirst();
        buffer.removeFirst();
        buffer.removeFirst();

        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, buffer::removeFirst);
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, buffer::removeLast);
    }

    @Test
    public void populateAndRemove() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();
        buffer.addLast(5); // [5]
        buffer.addLast(6); // [5, 6]
        buffer.addLast(7); // [5, 6, 7]

        buffer.removeFirst();   // Should remove the 5

        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(1));

        Assert.assertEquals(6, (int)buffer.getFromLast(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, (int)buffer.getFromLast(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void populateAndRemoveManyTimes() {
        RingBuffer<Integer> buffer = new RingBuffer<>();

        // This should result in the buffer always containing between 3 and 5 elements.
        buffer.addLast(-1);
        buffer.addLast(-1);
        buffer.addLast(-1);
        for (int i=0; i < 100; i+=2) {
            buffer.addLast(i);
            buffer.addLast(i+1);
            buffer.removeFirst();
            buffer.removeFirst();
        }

        // Check that the buffer has only 3 elements
        Assert.assertEquals(3, buffer.size());
        // Check that these elements are [97, 98, 99]
        Assert.assertEquals(97, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(98, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(1));
        Assert.assertEquals(99, (int)buffer.getFromFirst(2));

        // Check that the buffer has not grown in capacity to some absurd size
        // Will use 8 since my implementation will probably grow by doubling the backing array size.
        Assert.assertTrue(buffer.capacity() <= 8);
    }
}
```

By the way, I *know* this never shrinks the backing array, even if the number of elements in the `RingBuffer` drops well below the capacity. I don't consider this to be an issue for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Observations

- The class is not thread-safe, so why is method `doubleBackingArraySize` synchronized?
- All methods perform some sort of redundancy in circular incrementation and decrementation. This kind of arithmetic could be placed in 2 separate methods, which you would then call in the other methods to have more DRY code.
- Deciding when to allocate more space is a repeating code block that could be placed into a helper method.
- You present a great set of unit tests.

---

#### Circular arithmetic

These could be the reusable helpers methods. Naming conventions conform Java's implementation of [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue-source.html).

```
final int inc(int i) {
    return ++i % items.length;
}

final int dec(int i) {
    return (--i + items.length) % items.length;
}
```

---

#### DRY

Put the following recurring code into a helper:

> ```
> if ((nextIdx + 1) % backingArray.length == firstIdx) {
>     doubleBackingArraySize();
> }
> ```

```
final void CheckArrayCapacity() {
    if ((nextIdx + 1) % backingArray.length == firstIdx) {
        doubleBackingArraySize();
    }
}
```

---

#### Refactoring Code

For instance, `addFirst` could be written as:

```
public void addFirst(T x) {
    CheckArrayCapacity();
    firstIdx = dec(firstIdx);
    backingArray[firstIdx] = x;
}
```

instead of:

> ```
> public void addFirst(T x) {
>     if ((nextIdx + 1) % backingArray.length == firstIdx) {
>         doubleBackingArraySize();
>     }
>
>     firstIdx -= 1;
>     // Note: in Java -1 % n == -1
>     if (firstIdx < 0) {
>         firstIdx += backingArray.length;
>     }
>     backingArray[firstIdx] = x;
> }
> ```

All other methods could be written in a succinct way as above.

Comment: Great, those refactorings are much cleaner.

Adding `synchronized` was just a bad habit - I thought "Oh, I'm modifying the backing array, better not have two threads trying to do this at once!". But there's so many other places that this isn't thread-safe that it was just misleading. I've removed it now.